# ActionCable connections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

Does `ActionCable.server.connections.map(&:connection_identifier)` always return the same result as `ActionCable.server.connection_identifiers`?

I could not really figure it out judging from the Rails documentation for ActionCable...